# ¿se puede utilizar PHPSpreadsheet sin necesidad de composer?

Tags: php, composer, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, libreria

estoy intentando utilizar PHPSpreadsheet sin composer descargandolo de forma manual pero siempre que lo utilizo aparecen errores la version que utilizo es la master.

```
    <?php

require 'PhpSpreadsheet-master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Spreadsheet.php';
require 'PhpSpreadsheet-master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/IOFactory.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

// Crear un nuevo libro de trabajo de Excel
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

// Obtener la hoja activa
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Escribir datos en la hoja
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hola');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Mundo');

// Guardar el libro de trabajo en un archivo
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('ejemplo.xlsx');

echo "Excel generado exitosamente en ejemplo.xlsx";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es porque PhpSpreadSheet necesita unas dependencias, que no estás resolviendo, además de que se hacen muchísimos `require` (conté como 80).

Debido a lo anterior, los desarrolladores asumen que usas **Composer** para que resuelva las dependencias y con el `autolader` del proyecto ya no tengas que hacer importaciones a mano.

---

Pero si insistes en hacer esto manualmente, recomiendo hagas los siguientes cambios para que crees un [autoloader](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.spl-autoload-register.php) que importe las dependencias por ti.

[!Advertencia!] Esto vale para PHPSpreadSheet 1.29 (oct-2023) y puede cambiar en el futuro.

(1) Cambiar la ruta de PHPSpreadSheet, que quede similar a como está en los namespaces.
Debe quedar: `PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/[archivos]`

(2) Descargar [PHP Simple Caché](https://github.com/php-fig/simple-cache/releases/tag/3.0.0)
Debe quedar: `Psr/SimpleCache/[archivos]`

(3) Descargar [ZipStream](https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP/releases/tag/2.4.0). Por el momento (oct-2023) no funciona la versión más reciente debido a un cambio de directorios propuesto desde la 3.0. Usar la versión 2.4 como máximo.
Debe quedar: `ZipStream/[archivos]`

(4) Descargar [PHP Enum](https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum/releases/tag/1.8.4)
Debe quedar: `MyClabs/Enum/[archivos]`

Ahora puedes colocar un **autoloader** en el archivo, o importar alguno que ya tengas en el proyecto.

```php
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $req_class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    // echo $req_class . PHP_EOL; // <-- Descomentar para ver las importaciones
    require $req_class;
});

// Crear un nuevo libro de trabajo de Excel
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

// Obtener la hoja activa
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Escribir datos en la hoja
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hola');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Mundo');

// Guardar el libro de trabajo en un archivo
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('ejemplo.xlsx');

echo "Excel generado exitosamente en ejemplo.xlsx";
```